# What does type <U extends SimpleArgs, R> extends BasicAsyncFunc<U, R> mean?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have below declared types,

```
import { ReadonlyDeep } from 'type-fest';

// We don't allow null. undefined is required instead.
export type SimpleArgs = (string | number | boolean | undefined)[];

export type BasicAsyncFunc<U extends SimpleArgs, R> = (...args: U) => Promise<ReadonlyDeep<R>>;

interface Memoized<U extends SimpleArgs, R> extends BasicAsyncFunc<U, R> {
  cache_size: () => number;
  clear_cache: () => void;
}
```

Here is the definition of `memoized_async`,

```
const memoize_async = <R, U extends SimpleArgs>(
  options: { ttl: number; size: number },
  f: BasicAsyncFunc<U, R>,
): Memoized<U, R> => {
  
  return Object.assign(newFun, {
    cache_size: () => {
      return 0;
    },
    clear_cache: () => {
    },
  })
};
```

I understand `SimpleArgs` could array of primitives.

*What type `memoized_async` infers to?*

Comment: Whoever flagged _Does this answer your question_ please check if that has an answer before closing.

Comment: [Please edit your original question on this topic and do not re-post it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/7054/511366).